# How to clear karma warn web-server 404 error for Service method call?

Tags: testcase, jasmine

I am new to TDD. I have configured the karma and gulp for my sources to generate the code coverage. My karma configuration file is given below:

```
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'IE', 'Firefox', 'MyHeadlessChrome'],
        frameworks: ['jquery-1.10.2', 'jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        files: [
        '**/**/**/**/**.*',
        
        {
            pattern: 'js/**/**/**.html',
            watched: true,
            served: true,
            included: false
        }
        ],
        port:9878,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 1000000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 1000000,
        captureTimeout: 1000000,
        retryLimit: 5,
```

While execution test cases, I am getting below error, a method was in service. It shows that, method was not found.

My package.json configuration is given below:

```json
    "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-html-reporter": "^0.5.2",
    "ghooks": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-csslint": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-lesshint": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery-1x": "^1.10.2",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-html-detailed-reporter": "^1.1.20",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-jquery-2": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0"
     },
```

The karma-warning is given below:

```
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.395:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /Initialize
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.397:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /GetData
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.738:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /GetData
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.741:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /GetData
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.744:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /GetData
    06:42:21 [2] [33m13 10 2017 16:14:06.748:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /GetData
```

How to avoid the ajax call in karma test runner? And could anyone tell me how to stop ajax call in jasmine or karma?